# Git Clone and composer install on docker

Tags: php, docker, github, docker-compose, composer-php

I hope you are all safe and well,

I have a question regarding docker and cloning from GitHub.

When I run docker compose up, everything works as it should, part from when I get to the cloning stage. It goes through the process of cloning the master of repo into the folder but does not actually create it, so when I get to the point where I want to install composer via the RUN composer install command, it fails because it actually hasn't cloned the repo and I am guessing this is because it is waiting for the whole build process to finish?

If that is the case, is there a command I can use in the Dockerfile to make it wait or even depend on there being a cloned repo in the root of the app?

If not, can I put composer as a separate container and have it depend on the php service to clone the repo?

Here is a copy of my php docker file.

FROM php:7.3

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /app/
RUN mkdir CREATEDFOLDER
RUN cd CREATEDFOLDER
RUN git init
RUN git remote add origin https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USER/REPO.git
RUN git pull origin dev

WORKDIR /app/CREATEDFOLDER/
RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Showing your Dockerfile (or a trimmed-down version that still has the same issue) would probably help in seeing what may be happening

Comment: In general, you should run `git clone` on the host, not from inside Docker, and you should run build-time tools like `composer` in your Dockerfile, not as a separate Compose container.

Comment: I will edit my post with my docker file.

Comment: So @DavidMaze would you just put your dev setup in a container then clone manually etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "but does not actually create it"? What happens instead? Also, if cloning does not work, how is this problem related to PHP, or Composer?

Comment: In general I do my development using host-native tools without Docker; then I don't have to deal with the complexities of it being an isolated filesystem, with a separate network, where my IDE can't directly access the code or tools, and so on.  I build and deploy containers for final integration testing and production deployments.